# Use sparkSession,When I read the parquet file, I get type not yet supported error message

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Use sparkSession,When I read the parquet file, I get the following error
my code :

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("/Users/shaokai.li/Downloads/test.parquet")
```

error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Parquet type not yet supported: INT64 (TIMESTAMP_MILLIS);
```

I searched online for a long time and could not find the answer。
I hope someone can answer for me，thanks!

Comment: The message is clear- the original type TIMESTAMP_MILLIS is not supported in spark-parquet. Here is the code of Spark https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/75cf369c742e7c7b68f384d123447c97be95c9f0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala#L99
 You can try to load data without that timestamp column. 
If you need more specific help it would be good to share the dataset you try to load.

Comment: After seeing the source code, I found that spark supports the INT64 (TIMESTAMP_MILLIS) type. However,it's after the 2.3 version, thank you for your answer. I successfully solved the problem. Thanks again!